# How to deal with out-of-vocaboular words in NLP applications when word embedding is used?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, named-entity-recognition, word-embedding

The following NLP application uses word embedding. But I am not sure what if a word in an input text is not available in the embedding. Does anybody know what is the standardard practice to deal with words that are not in the embedding for NLP (or NER in particular)? Thanks.

https://guillaumegenthial.github.io/sequence-tagging-with-tensorflow.html

Answer (score 1):

In general, having a few OOV words is guaranteed to happen regardless of your domain and model. What's important is recognizing the impact these have on your task and taking the appropriate measures:

1. Find out how many OOV words your entire corpus has and whether their frequency is high enough to warrant any action other than ignoring them (either at a word level or at a higher level, e.g. skip sentences containing OOV words)
2. If your data is domain-specific and you have a few repeating OOV words (such as technical jargon, scientific terms etc.), tools like fastText (https://fasttext.cc/) will allow you to quickly train local embeddings.

Comment: What about punctuation marks like ',', '.', '!'? They are not in word embedding. But obviously they should not be ignored. How to deal with them?

Comment: Depending on the model, punctuation marks can be treated as _functional_ words (thus carrying no semantic vector but rather infulencing sentence semantics through some higher-level function), or be assigned a vector like the rest of the words. If the model you're using has no vectors for punctuation, and you think you absolutely need them, try looking for one that does.

Comment: But does fasttext allow punctuations? It seems that punctuations are not allowed. At least in some fasttext examples, punctuations are filtered out first for building the fasttext model. Or you know an embedding package that allows punctuations?

Comment: Why do you want your punctuations to have embeddings in the first place? Most algorithms will have trivialized the impact of punctuations due to frequency undersampling anyway.